# MongoDB: How to get the sub-document that contains the lowest value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Given the following document...

```
{ "_id": ObjectId("56116d8e4a0000c9006b57ac"), "name": "Stock 1", "items" [
    { "price": 1.50, "desc": "Item 1" }
    { "price": 1.70, "desc": "Item 2" }
    { "price": 1.10, "desc": "Item 3" }
  ]
}
```

I want to get the item with the lowest price. Here below is my attempt to sort prices from lowest to highest:

```
db.stock.wip.aggregate([
  {$unwind: "$items"}, 
  {$sort: {"items.price":1}}, 
  {$group: {_id:"$_id", items: {$push:"$items"}}}
]);
```

... and here is the result:

```
"result" : [
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("56116d8e4a0000c9006b57ac"),
    "items" : [
      {
        "price" : 1.10,
        "desc" : "Item 3"
      },
      {
        "price" : 1.50,
        "desc" : "Item 1"
      },
      {
        "price" : 1.70,
        "desc" : "Item 2"
      }
    ]
  }
],
"ok" : 1
```

How do I just get *Item 3* (the cheapest)? This is the result I'm looking for:

```
{
  "price" : 1.10,
  "desc" : "Item 3"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to write an aggregation query starting from your own, by slightly changed the `$group` stage and adding an additional `$project` step:

```
db.stock.wip.aggregate([
  {$unwind: "$items"}, 
  {$sort: {"items.price":1}}, 
  {$group: {
    _id:null, 
    lowestItem: {$first:"$items"}}},
  {$project: {_id: 0, price: "$lowestItem.price", desc: "$lowestItem.desc"}}
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the $first operator instead of $push, then do a $project:

```
db.stock.wip.aggregate([
  {$unwind: "$items"}, 
  {$sort: {"items.price":1}},
  {$group: {_id:"$_id", items: {$first:"$items"}}},
  { $project: {
    _id: 0,
    price: "$items.price",
    desc: "$items.desc",
  }}
]);
```

If you want to limit results only to the first item on the collection, add a {$limit:1} operator after the $sort:

```
db.stock.wip.aggregate([
  {$unwind: "$items"}, 
  {$sort: {"items.price":1}},
  {$limit:1},
  {$group: {_id:"$_id", items: {$first:"$items"}}},
  { $project: {
    _id: 0,
    price: "$items.price",
    desc: "$items.desc",
  }}
]);
```